# How to pull an array from collections using mongodb in codeigniter

Tags: mongodb, codeigniter

I have a collection like this in this collection I need to pull or remove the details from array where login date = 2015-12-23.Rest of the array should be same

```
Array
(
    [_id] => 1
    [user_id] => 2
    [work_details] => Array
        (
           [0] => Array
                (
                    [login_date] => 2015-12-23
                    [work_history] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [details] => gsdgsdgd
                                    [datetime] => 2015-12-23 12:54:12
                                )

                        )

                )
           [1] => Array
                (
                    [login_date] => 2015-12-24
                    [work_history] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [details] => ffgdf dfgdfh
                                    [datetime] => 2015-12-24 12:54:12
                                )

                        )

                )


        )
)
```

I have tried like this

```
$this->mongo_db->where('login_date', "2015-12-23")->unset_field('login_date.$')->update('masterCollection');
$this->mongo_db->pull('login_date', NULL)->update('masterCollection');
```

but its  not working

After removing the record I need the array like this

```
Array
(
    [_id] => 1
    [user_id] => 2
    [work_details] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [login_date] => 2015-12-24
                    [work_history] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [details] => ffgdf dfgdfh
                                    [datetime] => 2015-12-24 12:54:12
                                )

                        )

                )


        )
)
```

Is there any solution for this.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the query that I used to remove the data:

```
db.testso.update({_id: 2},{ $pull: { work_details: {login_date:"2015-12-25"}}});
```

It successfully removed the array with the login_date: "2015-12-25".

Here is the sample data that I used:

```
{ "_id" : 1, "user_id" : 2, "work_details" : [ { "login_date" : "2015-12-23", "work_history" : [ { "details" : "abcd", "day" : "ancxc" } ] } ] }
{ "_id" : 2, "user_id" : 3, "work_details" : [ { "login_date" : "2015-12-24", "work_history" : [ { "details" : "abcd1", "day" : "ancxc1" } ] }, { "login_date" : "2015-12-25", "work_history" : [ { "details" : "abcd2", "day" : "ancxc2" } ] } ] }
```